# I have a question about the standard epidemic SIR model: How do I get the values $\beta$ and $\gamma$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling

I have a question about the standard epidemic SIR model:
$$\frac{dS}{dt}=-\frac{\beta IS}{N},$$
$$\frac{dI}{dt}=\frac{\beta IS}{N}-\gamma I,$$
$$\frac{dR}{dt}=\gamma I.$$

How do I get the values $\beta$ and $\gamma$?

My question arises because I want to perform a real simulation applied to the COVID case. I have already done some research and have not found anything useful.

I hope you can help me, thank you.

Comment: Do note that the data assembled by the medical bureaucracies are not scientific measurements. For instance there is largely no distinction made between screening (low false negative) and diagnosis (reduced false positive), the difference is just called "asymptomatic". You may have to compensate for that, for example by also varying the population size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the SIR model shown, the $\frac{\beta IS}{N}$ term corresponds to people getting sick, and $\gamma I$ represents people becoming no longer sick, either by recovering or passing. I'm going to assume that $N$ is the total initial population of your modeled area.

To find $\beta$, we use the fact that the rate of new cases is given by $\frac{\beta IS}{N}$. It's probably best to look at data near the beginning of the pandemic, since in that case very few people have been infected, so $S\approx N$ is a reasonable assumption. Then you can take the ratio between new cases and current cases (averaged over multiple days to reduce error) to find $\beta$.

To find $\gamma$, we can simply divide the number of new deaths/recoveries by the total infections for the day. Given what we know about recovery times (usually around 14 days), I would not expect this quantity to be consistent over the course of the pandemic, especially in the exponential growth portion at the beginning. I would suggest taking data from times the case count was plateauing or dropping.